# Selenium unable to find element that soup can so unable to click using python selenium and Beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, onclick, click

I am trying to click on a onclick item but Selenium doesn't find it.
Element is as follows.

```
<a tabindex="0" onkeypress="loginKeyboardEvent(event)" role="button" aria-pressed="false" class="waves-effect waves-light"> Login </a>
```

I have tried variations on the following. BeautifulSoup finds the element but Selenium doesn't. I have found in BS that the element is in the 4th div of 'wave-effect...' Selenium returns an empty list so cannot find even the first instance of the class='wave...'

```
driver.get("https://www.woolworthsrewards.com.au/")
time.sleep(5)
page_source=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
products_selector = soup.find_all('a', class_='waves-effect waves-light')
login_link=(products_selector[3].text)
print(login_link)

p_sel=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'waves-effect waves-light')
print(p_sel)
```

Using selenium to get page-source does not return the element but BS does. Though using the xpath in selenium still does not find the element

How can I send a click event with selenium when it can't find the element and BS does not have a click event.
Once clicked it will open a side panel to enter login details, though if I can't open the side panel, I can't get to enter the login details.
the xpath to the anchor is

```
xpath - /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/wr-header-element/header/nav/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a
```

but again, selenium does nto find it

Comment: `p_sel` is a list: you should print `p_sel[0].text`. Better, you should use Waits.

Comment: p.sel returns an empty list.
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to access those links. Assuming you have a working Selenium setup:

```
[...]
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

url = 'https://www.woolworthsrewards.com.au/'
driver.get(url)

for e in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="waves-effect waves-light"]'))):
    print(e.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
PARTNERS
HELP & FAQS
HOW IT WORKS
LOGIN
JOIN
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: Thanks worked a treat. I don't understand the //a[@class notation in the web driver yet and used an external wait command. I should use webdriver wait instead

Comment: That's how you write XPATH locators. Selenium docs should have more details on XPATH locators.

Comment: This is not finding the one element I need. It is finding 4 elements returned into1 list item. Using a notation that I have never come across on a web page. Doubt it is actually a clickable element in this format.

Comment: Ok, so the webdriverwait allows me to then use the html xpath retrieved from the browser view element. It errors indicating the element is not interactable. This gives me somewhere to go though.

Comment: Ok, so I solved my issue by adding an if statement
for e in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="waves-effect waves-light"]'))):
    print(e.text)
    if e.text =='LOGIN':
        e.click()
But for some reason my Chrome testing browser witht he Chronme driver does not show the 1st 3 items,
PARTNERS
HELP & FAQS
HOW IT WORKS
and on click results in not authorised to authenticate on this server. But if I do it manually all is good.

Comment: If you want to click on 'LOGIN' link, then you can do `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text() = " Login "]'))).click()` -- you should have clarify this in your original post. I also get 'not authorised' when clicking on that button, likely a matter of IP/Location. Maybe your IP was blacklisted due to scraping the website too many times?

Comment: I am now using the webdriver.wait.until statements today. I also think the reason I was getting the Access Denied error was because my User Agent option was set with Linux rather than WinNT. The machine is Win 10. and referenced an older Chrome version. The one that works on my machine is user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'